# .internetconnect Modification

Tags: iphone, network, security

My network has a .internetconnect file which allows iDevices to connect to the network. However, they also have a really irritating rule which means we have to passcode our devices to get on, which is the last thing I'd like to do.

I've got the file open in the   or   display, but I'm unclear which one defines the passcode as on - can someone help me out?

It's a work network so I can't easily share the file but there is nothing that obviously defines the passcode as on.

Thanks!

The file can be found [here](http://files-insrv.cf.ac.uk/eduroam_cardiff.mobileconfig).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the entire passcode policy:

```
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>Configures security-related items.</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>Passcode Policy</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>uk.ac.cardiff.insrv.eduroam.iphone3.7.passcodepolicy</string>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>Cardiff University</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>com.apple.mobiledevice.passwordpolicy</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>215E70FE-858E-48A8-9F34-7BD7BEE495C4</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>allowSimple</key>
        <true/>
        <key>forcePIN</key>
        <true/>
        <key>maxGracePeriod</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>maxInactivity</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>minLength</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
        <key>pinHistory</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
```

Comment: It worked! I can't believe I didn't think of that, but nontheless, here's your bounty :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might not work because of all the SSH keys and what look like hashcodes in the file but at lines 419-420 we have the lines

```
<key>forcePIN</key>
<true/>
```

Changing line 420 to `<false/>` is certainly worth a shot. :D

Comment: BTW, I would have added this as a comment on the question but my rep says I can't.

Comment: Maybe I opened up the wrong file when I tried, but I definitely didn't see that. I'll have another look now :)

Comment: It didn't play along, but thanks anyway :)